# Pandas Dataframe - Change the data structure (re-organize)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I read a csv file with theses data:

```
CatPart 1           
CodeItem    1           
12  15  
5.5 3   

CodeItem    2           
7   6   
2   7       

CatPart 5           
CodeItem    0           
1   25  
1.5 7   

CodeItem    8           
25  1   
22  1
```

And I would like to have this format in the dataframe

```
CatPart CodeItem Weight Nb
1 1 12 15   
1 1 5.5 3       
1 2 7 6 
1 2 2 7 
5 0 1 25
5 0 1.5 7   
5 8 25  1
5 8 22  1
```

So first I create header with the colums name
df.columns = ["Weight", "Nb", "CatPart", "CodeItem"]
and I removed the empty line. My strategy was to copy the value in the row CatPart to the column Cartpart, this part was okay (see below) and after duplicate the value to replace the nan until the next value (do the same CodeItem) and then delete the row CatPart and CodeItem but I didn't find a way to duplicate the value.

```
Weight      Nb  CatPart CodeItem
CatPart     1   1   nan
CodeItem    1   nan 1
12          15  nan nan
5.5         3   nan nan
CodeItem    2   2   nan
7           6   nan nan
2           7   nan nan
CatPart     5   5   nan
CodeItem    0   nan 0
1           25  nan nan
1.5         7   nan nan
CodeItem    8   8   nan
25          1   nan nan
22          1   nan nan
```

Or maybe their is a easier way to do that but I don't see it.

Thanks for your help!
F.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a csv file.

- When `CatPart` or `CodeItem` changes, they are marked with the field at the start of the line, followed by a variable number of spaces and then the value
- `weight` & `nb` always appear on the same line separated by space.
- A record can be considered filled when the following information exists `CatPart`, `CodeItem`, `weight`, `nb`.

One way to restructure the document is to iterate over the lines and yielding records when they are filled.

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd


text = """CatPart 1
CodeItem    1
12  15
5.5 3

CodeItem    2
7   6
2   7

CatPart 5
CodeItem    0
1   25
1.5 7
CodeItem    8
25  1
22  1"""

records = []
part, item, weight, nb = '', '', '', ''

for line in io.StringIO(text):
    if line.startswith('CatPart'):
        _, part = re.split('\s+', line.strip())
    if line.startswith('CodeItem'):
        _, item = re.split('\s+', line.strip())
    if re.match('^\d+', line):
        weight, nb = re.split('\s+', line.strip())
        records.append([part, item, weight, nb])
```

Note that I've used `io.StringIO` to create a file in memory for this example. Replace that with something like this:

```
with open('/path/to/my/file.txt') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        ...
```

Then pass the records into pandas.DataFrame constructor.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['CatPart', 'CatItem', 'weight', 'nb'])
```

produces the following output:

```
  CatPart CatItem weight  nb
0       1       1     12  15
1       1       1    5.5   3
2       1       2      7   6
3       1       2      2   7
4       5       0      1  25
5       5       0    1.5   7
6       5       8     25   1
7       5       8     22   1
```

However, until this point, I didn't convert any data from string. You can do the conversions as you read the data, or do it after structuring the data in a table using:

```
df = df.astype(float)
```